# Spring Cloud Config Server gives Connect Timeout Exception on Url -http://localhost:8888 When deployed on Dockers

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to shift my spring-boot microservices to dockers. My microservices are running absolutely fine when implemented on STS on the local system. But when I dockerize them I get a connection timeout error.

I am sharing my code snippets below:

**Docker-compose:**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  db:
    image: 'mysql:8.0.18'
    container_name: mysqldb
    ports:
      - '3300:3300'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=root
    networks:
      - truyum-nw
      - movie-cruiser-nw
    volumes:
      - './mysqldb:/var/lib/mysql'
      - './dbscripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d'
  config-server:
    image: spring-cloud-config-server
    build: ./spring-cloud-config-server
    container_name: spring-cloud-config-server
    ports:
      - '8888:8888'
    networks:
      - truyum-nw
      - movie-cruiser-nw
  eureka:
    image: eureka-discovery-service
    build: ./eureka-discovery-service
    container_name: eureka-discovery
    ports:
      - '8761:8761'
    depends_on:
      - config-server
      - db
    networks:
      - truyum-nw
      - movie-cruiser-nw
  zuul:
    image: zuul-service
    build: ./zuul-gateway
    container_name: zuul-bridge
    ports:
      - '8762:8762'
    depends_on:
      - eureka
      - config-server
    networks:
      - truyum-nw
      - movie-cruiser-nw
  auth-service:
    image: auth-service
    build: ./Authentication-service
    container_name: auth-service
    ports:
      - '9100:9100'
    depends_on:
      - eureka
      - config-server
    networks:
      - truyum-nw
      - movie-cruiser-nw
  menu-item-service:
    image: menu-item-service
    build: ./menuitem-service
    container_name: menu-item-service
    ports:
      - '34000:34000'
    depends_on:
      - eureka
      - config-server
      - zuul
      - db
      - auth-service
    networks:
      - truyum-nw
  cart-service:
    image: cart-service
    build: ./cart-service
    container_name: cart-service
    ports:
      - '34001:34001'
    depends_on:
      - eureka
      - config-server
      - zuul
      - db
      - menu-item-service
      - auth-service
    networks:
      - truyum-nw
  movie-service:
    image: movie-service
    build: ./movie-service
    container_name: movie-service
    ports:
      - '35000:35000'
    depends_on:
      - eureka
      - config-server
      - db
      - zuul
      - auth-service
    networks:
      - movie-cruiser-nw
  favourite-service:
    image: favourite-service
    build: ./favorite-service
    container_name: favourite-service
    ports:
      - '35001:35001'
    depends_on:
      - eureka
      - config-server
      - db
      - zuul
      - auth-service
      - movie-service
    networks:
      - movie-cruiser-nw
networks:
  truyum-nw:
    name: truyum-nw
    driver: bridge
  movie-cruiser-nw:
    name: movie-cruiser-nw
    driver: bridge
```

**application.properties** of **spring-cloud-config-server**:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri = https://github.com/satyamthedeveloper/Stage4_Week2_841418_SatyamKumar
server.port=8888
```

**application.properties** of **Eureka-Discovery-Server**:

```
spring.application.name=discoveryservice
spring.cloud.config.uri = http://spring-cloud-config-server:8888
```

When I do `docker-compose up` and I check `http://localhost:8888/discoveryservice/default` I get the result as

```
{
    "name": "discoveryservice",
    "profiles": [
        "default"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "8450532e432fb103ef30d0002fa254b23d2158d6",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://github.com/satyamthedeveloper/Stage4_Week2_841418_SatyamKumar/discoveryservice.properties",
            "source": {
                "server.port": "8761",
                "eureka.client.register-with-eureka": "false",
                "eureka.client.fetch-registry": "false",
                "info.app.name": "Spring Eureka Server Application"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "https://github.com/satyamthedeveloper/Stage4_Week2_841418_SatyamKumar/application.yml",
            "source": {
                "eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone": "http://eureka-discovery:8761/eureka",
                "logging.level.org.springframework.web": "DEBUG",
                "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include": "*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But still, my `Eureka discovery service` starts on 8080 which is not accessible as I have not exposed it. I have tried a few of these steps which didn't help.

1. tried stopping and restarting discovery service when my cloud-config is up and ready.
2. tried it separately without docker-compose by creating network still it not worked.

I am not sure why my services are not able to fetch the link which I can easily fetch using URL.

[image: This is a screenshot of my log which I get every time, no matter whatever I try.]

Answer (score 2):

The name that you must refer in your eureka configuration for config server is only `config-server` since this is the service name in your compose yaml.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is wrong in your configuration. The `config-server` will be discovered by the name given in compose file. What you can do is to ssh into your container and try to ping and connect to config-server manually.
the command: `docker exec -it <containerid> bash`
Check as well the file `/etc/resolve.conf` inside the container

Comment: I was able to connect with config-server manually using Postman and Browser. somewhere my microservices was not able to connect to it. I finally got to resolve the issue by given method below.

Answer (score 2):

After spending two days on it, I got to resolve this issue following way:

I shifted the properties which I was defining in `application.properties` to `bootstrap.yml`. The changes are as followed.

**bootstrap.yml** of **spring-cloud-config-server**:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: config-server
    cloud:
        config:
            server:
                git:
                    uri: https://github.com/satyamthedeveloper/Stage4_Week2_841418_SatyamKumar
                    clone-on-start: true
```

**bootstrap.yml** of **Eureka-Discovery-Server**:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: discoveryservice
    cloud:
        config:
            fail-fast: true
            retry:
                maxAttempts: 200
                maxInterval: 10000 
            uri: http://spring-cloud-config-server:8888
```

The reason behind such error was understood after getting to know the difference between `bootstrap.yml` and `application.properties`:

**Use of application.properties is**:

> We use application.yml or application.properties for configuring the
> application context.
>
> When a Spring Boot application starts, it creates an application
> context that doesn't need to be explicitly configured – it's already
> autoconfigured. However, Spring Boot offers different ways to override
> these properties.

**And use of bootstrap.yml is**:

> We use bootstrap.yml or bootstrap.properties for configuring the
> bootstrap context. This way we keep the external configuration for
> bootstrap and main context nicely separated.
>
> The bootstrap context is responsible for loading configuration
> properties from the external sources and for decrypting properties in
> the local external configuration files.
>
> When the Spring Cloud application starts, it creates a bootstrap
> context. The first thing to remember is that the bootstrap context is
> the parent context for the main application.
>
> Another key point to remember is that these two contexts share the
> Environment, which is the source of external properties for any Spring
> application. In contrast with the application context, the bootstrap
> context uses a different convention for locating the external
> configuration.

You can refer the following blog for more specific information:
[Difference between Application.properties and Bootstrap.yml with example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bootstrap-properties#:%7E:text=Although%20both%20of%20them%20share,is%20searching%20for%20an%20application.)

Answer (score 0):

actually while running docker-compose.yml one image(for ex localhost:8761) doesn't know about localhost:8888(your config server).

your application.properties/ yml file is giving back localhost:port to eureka image which needs to get connect with other image/instance but one image is expecting other image uri i.e **http://service_name:port**
so you need to pass it externally as environment variable

Add enviroment variable config server uri under eureka image i.e
in **docker-compose.yml:**

```
 eureka:
image: eureka-discovery-service
build: ./eureka-discovery-service
container_name: eureka-discovery
ports:
  - '8761:8761'
depends_on:
  - config-server
environment: 
# Important for clients to register with config server
  
  - spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://config-server:8888
  - db
networks:
  - truyum-nw
  - movie-cruiser-nw
```

also if you need to pass eureka in any eureka client you need to pass it as environment variable under eureka client image

```
 environment: 
# Important for clients to register with eureka
   eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery-service:8761/eureka/
```

in the above code discover-service is the service name of eureka server (in port 8761).

Comment: I have a same problem running Spring Boot Microservices on Kubernetes. Can you help me if you have any idea about it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75173708/kubernetes-issue-in-spring-boot-microservices-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-c